# Accessing 2-dimensional array via pointer using pointer math: Array type required [Delphi]

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointer-arithmetic

I’m perfectly avare that pointer math in *Delphi* should be used with special care, but I still don’t get where am I wrong here.
Let’s take a look on the following type definition:

```
program Project26;
{$POINTERMATH ON}

type
  TCalibrationTable = array [0 .. 3] of byte;
  PCalibrationTable = ^TCalibrationTable;
```

Now I need 2 arrays, each of them having 3 elements of `TCalibrationTable` (ultimately they are 2-dimensional, 3 × 4 arrays).
And also need a header which points to a pair of such array objects.

```
var
  table0: array [0 .. 2] of TCalibrationTable;
  table1: array [0 .. 2] of TCalibrationTable;

  header: array [0 .. 1] of PCalibrationTable;
```

Let’s initialize the header: the most comfortable way to access an array by a pointer is to assign it the first element’s address, then simply index the pointer to get an arbitrary element.

```
begin
  header[0] := @table0[0];
  header[1] := @table1[0];
```

Now, `header[0]` being a `PCalibrationTable`, I can use it to index it in order to get arbitrary `TCalibrationTable` typed elements from an array. In this way `header[0][2]` **SHOULD BE** a `TCalibrationTable`, that is, an array of 4 elements of `byte`.

But the following assignment will give a build error: *Array type required*.

```
  header[0][2][3] := 100;
end.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the pointer indirection from the header, you get this:

```
type
  TCalibrationTable = array [0 .. 3] of byte;
  PCalibrationTable = ^TCalibrationTable;
var
  header: array [0 .. 1] of PCalibrationTable;
```

becomes

```
type
  TCalibrationTable = array [0 .. 3] of byte;
var
  header: array [0 .. 1] of TCalibrationTable;
```

or

```
var
  header: array [0 .. 1] of array [0 .. 3] of byte;
```

or

```
var
  header: array [0 .. 1,0 .. 3] of byte;
```

In other words, a 2-dimensional array.

What you need is this:

```
type
  TCalibrationTable = array [0 .. 3] of byte;
  TCalibrationArr = ARRAY[0..2] OF TCalibrationTable;
  PCalibrationArr = ^TCalibrationArr;

var
  table0: TCalibrationArr;
  table1: TCalibrationArr;

  header: array [0 .. 1] of PCalibrationArr;
```

you can then do

```
header[0] := @table0;
header[1] := @table1;
header[0][1][2]:=123;
```

Comment: This is exactly I want to avoid as this trivial code is derived from a real one where things are a little bit complicated. Actually the length of table0 and table1 are not known at compile time, they are rather objects created dynamically, but from the point of view of redirection this thing is irrelevant.

Comment: By the way, your example should be rather used in the following way: ```header[0]^[1][2] := 123```, am I right? As ```header[0]``` point directly to a 2-dimension array.

Comment: @ZoltánBíró _header[0]^[1][2] := 123_ and _header[0][1][2] := 123_ are the same in Delphi, just as _MainForm.Caption_ is the same as _MainForm^.Caption_ (MainForm is in reality a POINTER to an instance, but the delphi language allows omitting the pointer dereference when the compiler can do so without ambiguity).

Comment: @ZoltánBíró If you want to ask about arrays whose length is dynamic, shouldn't that information be in the question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, no, as it would complicate a lot the question and it’s irrelevant: I need rather an explanation why this doesn’t work, not necessarily a workaround. In case of a programming language an illogical behavior scares me much more than a task that I cannot solve myself.

Comment: @HeartWare nor sure whether you already noticed but you’ve just answered my question. Actually this dereference omitting (which obviously conflicts the pointermath logic) makes here the confusion.

Comment: @ZoltánBíró Information about the fact that in reality you are using dynamic arrays **should** be included in your question. Why? Because dynamic multidimensional arrays are handled by Delphi differently as static multidimensional arrays. You see in Delphi dynamic multidimensional arrays is actually array of arrays. So outher leverl of multidimensional arrays is array whose items are references to other (inner) arrays. And then each inner arrays hods the information in its own memory block and thus can even have different size. ...

Comment: ... So using pointer math with dynamic multidimensional arrays won't work as they are not stored in a single continuous memory block like static multidimensional arrays are.

Comment: @SilverWarior, negative, they indeed work in the same way. Assume you have ```dynarray: array of array [0 .. 3] of byte```. Let’s say ```setlength(dynarray, 3); pdynarray := @dynarray[0]```. Well, if you take a look on a memory dump of ```pdynarray^``` you’ll see “multidimensional arrays stored in a single continuous memory block like static multidimensional arrays are”. The problem here is the stupid thing that Delphi allows omitting pointer dereference for array pointers in extended syntax in this way making pointer math ambiguous for 2 dim arrays, as @Heartware stated. Pity for the downvote